# How can the line wrapping width on Sphinx with alabaster be increased?

Tags: html, css, python-sphinx

Is there a simple way to increase the line wrapping width when using `html_theme = 'alabaster'` using `Sphinx` 1.3.1?

`alabaster` is now the default theme and looks great except that it wraps lines very tightly, and I'd like to be able to configure this.

Comment: Have you looked into the theme at all? Is it actually line breaking, or is that just the div width?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The alabaster theme sets the default page width to `940px` using CSS. You can alter this using one of its options `page_width`. Valid values for this can be anything from `auto` to a **px**, **cm** or **em** or even a **percentage**. *For more on valid values [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp) has a good page where you can play around with things.* To set the page width you would add the following to your `conf.py` replacing `auto` with your desired width

```
html_theme_options = {
    'page_width': 'auto',
}
```

The alabaster theme also includes the `sidebar_width` option that works in the exact same way as the `page_width` option. It defaults to `220px`. You can find more information on its theme options at it [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/alabaster).

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a better answer.  Note that this option requires `alabaster >= 0.7.6`.  I had to upgrade `alabaster` with `pip` to get this to work.

Comment: Not completely obvious to me - and difficult to find - the value passed in the dictionary has to be in `' '`.  In looking at normal CSS (w3schools) normally the value is passed without the quote.

Comment: Note that alabaster [extends](https://github.com/bitprophet/alabaster/blob/master/alabaster/theme.conf) Sphinx  [basic theme](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/themes/basic/theme.conf), so in addition to the `page_with`, you probably want to add `'body_max_width': 'auto',` to the `html_theme_options` dict.