# I'm using the sphinx theme alabaster. How can I get a wider screen on a PC?

Tags: window, themes, size, python-sphinx

The content part of the window is too narrow for my intended use.

I already tried     "body_max_width": "none" in html_theme_options.
I also tried 'custom.css' with
.wy-nav-content {    max-width: 75% !important; }
None of the above worked for me.
My conf.py file is basic 'out of the box' kind.
Thank you!

Comment: Does `page_width` work for you? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32258604/407651 and https://alabaster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#basics

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying content width of the Sphinx theme 'Read the Docs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211695/modifying-content-width-of-the-sphinx-theme-read-the-docs)

Comment: page_width can enlarge only a little bit the screen.
The other link by Steve is not useful. Thank you anyway.